# Why Does Laravel automatically add an index for constrained columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, indexing

Why Does Laravel automatically add an “**INDEX**” for this condition?

```
$table->foreignId('user_id')->nullable()
    ->constrained('users','id')
    ->onDelete('no action')
    ->onUpdate('no action');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Laravel** only adds a foreign key constraint and doesn't add **index** implicitly. But some databases such as MySQL automatically **index** foreign key columns.

When you define a **foreign key constraint** in your database table,  <s>an **index** will **not be created automatically** on the **foreign key** columns</s>  , as in the **PRIMARY KEY** constraint situation in which a clustered **index** will be **created automatically** when defining it. **It is highly recommended to create an index on the foreign key columns**, to enhance the performance of the joins between the primary and foreign keys, and also reduce the cost of maintaining the **relationship** between the **child** and **parent** tables. Before adding any new indexes, it is better to test on a development environment and monitor the overall performance after the implementation, to make sure that the added indexes improve performance and do not negatively impact the system performance.

Answer (score 4):

From https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

> MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan. In the referencing table, there must be an index where the foreign key columns are listed as the first columns in the same order. **Such an index is created on the referencing table automatically if it does not exist.** This index might be silently dropped later if you create another index that can be used to enforce the foreign key constraint. index_name, if given, is used as described previously.

Comment: (This is more correct and less diffuse than the previously accepted answer.)